# Installing web3.py from source, Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, mac-osx, web3.py

Trying to install web3.py from source and getting this error when doing a `pip install -e .` inside the web3 directory.

> RuntimeError: Format missing, but need one (identified source as text as no file with that name was found).
>
> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/t2/g8zfp3jd5y388nvcx5_f9qm00000gn/T/pip-build-AjPzos/ethereum-keyfile/

Reference: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/web3/3.16.2

Output:

```
$ pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///Users/joeyz/Projects/Eth/web3.py
Collecting cytoolz>=0.8.2 (from web3==4.0.0b2)
  Downloading cytoolz-0.9.0.tar.gz (443kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 450kB 2.1MB/s 
Collecting ethereum-abi-utils>=0.4.3 (from web3==4.0.0b2)
  Using cached ethereum-abi-utils-0.4.7.tar.gz
Collecting ethereum-keyfile>=0.3.0 (from web3==4.0.0b2)
  Using cached ethereum-keyfile-0.3.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Maybe try:

        brew install pandoc
    See http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/installing.html
    for installation options
    ---------------------------------------------------------------

    zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
    pypandoc.__init__: module references __file__


    !!! pandoc not found, long_description is bad, don't upload this to PyPI !!!



    Installed /private/var/folders/t2/g8zfp3jd5y388nvcx5_f9qm00000gn/T/pip-build-AjPzos/ethereum-keyfile/.eggs/pypandoc-1.4-py2.7.egg
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/t2/g8zfp3jd5y388nvcx5_f9qm00000gn/T/pip-build-AjPzos/ethereum-keyfile/setup.py", line 33, in <module>
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
      File "/Users/joeyz/Projects/Eth/web3.py/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/Users/joeyz/Projects/Eth/web3.py/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 333, in __init__
        _Distribution.__init__(self, attrs)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/Users/joeyz/Projects/Eth/web3.py/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 476, in finalize_options
        ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
      File "/private/var/folders/t2/g8zfp3jd5y388nvcx5_f9qm00000gn/T/pip-build-AjPzos/ethereum-keyfile/.eggs/setuptools_markdown-0.2-py2.7.egg/setuptools_markdown.py", line 22, in long_description_markdown_filename
        output = pypandoc.convert(markdown_filename, 'rst')
      File "/private/var/folders/t2/g8zfp3jd5y388nvcx5_f9qm00000gn/T/pip-build-AjPzos/ethereum-keyfile/.eggs/pypandoc-1.4-py2.7.egg/pypandoc/__init__.py", line 66, in convert
        raise RuntimeError("Format missing, but need one (identified source as text as no "
    RuntimeError: Format missing, but need one (identified source as text as no file with that name was found).

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/t2/g8zfp3jd5y388nvcx5_f9qm00000gn/T/pip-build-AjPzos/ethereum-keyfile/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

web3.py v4 is py3-only, and it appears that you're trying to build it with `python2.7`

If you want to build v3, which still supports py2, then check out the `v3` branch before running `pip install`. Note that v3 is on its way out, and v4 will go stable <sup>realsoonnow</sup>.

---

It also looks like you're getting a documentation build error.

> ```
> Maybe try:
>
>     brew install pandoc
> ```

Did you try this ^ ?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  I updated to py3 to avoid the issue altogether.  Thank you!